# Finding the sum of the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} ((n^2+1)^{1/2} - (n^3+1)^{1/3})$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, summation

I need help in finding the sum of the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} ((n^2+1)^{1/2} - (n^3+1)^{1/3})$ if it converges.

I can't even prove convergence. I tried comparison test. I tried telescoping or even sandwich the partial sums. But I could not get anything.

I also tried using the identity

$a-b = \frac{a^3-b^3}{a^2+ab+b^2}$

and even the identity for $a^6-b^6$

but it won't yield.

I found this one while going through some really old question papers of my college.

Please help.

Comment: Show the $n$th term is asymptotic to $\frac{1}{2n}$ viz. $\sqrt{n^2+1}-n\sim\frac{1}{2n},\,\sqrt[3]{n^3+1}-n\sim\frac{1}{3n^2}$.

Comment: Ahhhh. Add and subtract n. Did not see that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point is "finding the sum **if it converges**".

If we are able to show that the sum doesn't converge, then there is no need to find its sum.

To show divergency, it suffices to use Taylor expansion to show that $(n^2 + 1)^{1/2} = n + \frac 1{2n} + O(\frac 1{n^2})$ and $(n^3 + 1)^{1/3} = n + O(\frac 1{n^2})$ when $n$ tends to infinity.

These together give $$(n^2 + 1)^{1/2} - (n^3 + 1)^{1/3} = \frac 1{2n} + O(\frac 1{n^2})$$ when $n$ tends to infinity. Thus the divergency follows from the fact that the harmonic series is divergent and the series $\sum\frac 1{n^2}$ is convergent.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Taylor expansion for a sequence? It's that well defined?

Comment: @Guillerminho77 It's the Taylor expansion $(1 + x^2)^{1/2} = 1 + \frac 12 x^2 + \cdots$ applied with $x = \frac 1 n$. The details I omitted because the OP should be able to fill them in.

Answer (score 0):

Without series, we have

$$\sqrt{n^2+1}-\sqrt[3]{n^3+1} = \sqrt{n^2+1}- n + n - \sqrt[3]{n^3+1}$$

which allows us to use those conjugates without appealing to sixth order

$$= \frac{1}{n+\sqrt{n^2+1}} - \frac{1}{n^2+n\sqrt[3]{n^3+1}+(n^3+1)^{\frac{2}{3}}}$$

The divergence comes from the square root term.

Comment: Something is fishy. The second term should be negative since $n-(n^3+1)^{1/3}<0$.